# Log files are being generated every minute or so on S3 from Athena. How can I stop this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I started to see how Amazon Athena works on S3.  I had to setup a spot for log files to go.  I set that up.  Now that spot is getting a log file every 20 seconds to three minutes. Why?

I'm not (trying to) create a query on Athena now.  I've just run a couple of queries to see that they work.  What is going on and how can I make it stop?

Thanks.

Comment: What do the log files contain? What is an example name of the log file?

Comment: log2020-05-12-14-22-11-CE44512E54BB4EE5 is the name of one of the files.

Comment: Content:  e24d10623843367d6a60b01c791daa5b6d3bf35248894f3887a1020beac552fa azure-cpo-commerce [12/May/2020:13:45:40 +0000] 10.56.54.226 3272ee65a908a7677109fedda345db8d9554ba26398b2ca10581de88777e2b61 2CBC78133E958E2E REST.PUT.OBJECT log2020-05-12-13-45-40-48D7B3720A75C9C7 "PUT /azure-cpo-commerce/log2020-05-12-13-45-40-48D7B3720A75C9C7 HTTP/1.1" 200 - - 675 27 17 "-" "aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.590 Linux/4.9.184-0.1.ac.235.83.329.metal1.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.222-b10 java/1.8.0_222 vendor/Oracle_Corporation" - r6we2nyE8VNVXt/ccTXJXeOcBFEG4pX4HpB7/QlFDV1fU3HG1h9weF3vKP....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log files appear to be coming from [Amazon S3 server access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html).

To deactivate the logs:

- Go to your `azure-cpo-commerce` bucket in the Amazon S3 management console
- Click the **Properties** tab
- Click **Server access logging**
- Disable the logging